# Open chromium in kiosk mode at start with URLs from a text file

Tags: bash, chromium

I'm new to bash scripting and just a little familiar with basic Linux.
We've setup a Pi showing dashboards using the code below:

```
@chromium-browser --disable-infobars --disable-session-crashed-bubble --kiosk http://www.url.com
```

which is located in this directory `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`.

But I'd like to create a solution where the URLs that are opened are more easily maintained. Therefore, I figured I could create a .txt file, which a bash script could read and create the command with all the listed URLs.

This is what I've tried:

In `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
@point-rpi

@sh ~/startChrome.sh
```

In `/home/pi/startChrome.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="$HOME/websites.txt"
sites=""
while IFS= read -r var
do
  sites=$sites" "$var
done < "$input"

chromium-browser --disable-infobars --disable-session-crashed-bubble --kiosk $sites
```

Example content of `/home/pi/websites.txt`:

```
http://www.google.com
http://www.somewebsite.com
```

I've tried to test this by running the `startChrome.sh` file, but this returns an error:

```
pi@TeamMBA:~ $ sh startChrome.sh 
[977:977:0601/113521:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(271)] Gtk: cannot open display:
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Or maybe I'm overthinking this and there is an easier way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `export DISPLAY=:0.0` to my bash script solved my problem.

Comment: It would be appreciated if you could mark this answer as correct, since it solved your problem.

Comment: Yeah love to do that but I cannot accept my own answer yet as it does not allow me to do that yet ("you can accept your own answer in 2 days")

Comment: Ok, be sure to mark it as such when you can, thanks for the response.